# scroll bar going out at the bottom from the parent div

Tags: css

When i am applied padding:10px to the child div which have the height 100% and parent height 200px, when the content exceeded 200px of the height the scroll bar bottom is going outside. If i removes the padding its coming fine. How can we solve the problem without remove padding and adding inside the div?

http://jsfiddle.net/H2d77/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `overflow:auto;` to `.wrapper`

```
.wrapper{height:200px;width:300px; overflow:auto; border:1px solid red;margin:10px}

.innerDiv{height:100%;padding:10px}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H2d77/4/

Comment: i dont want add overflow:auto to .wrapper. I want only to .innerDiv

Comment: scroll bars should be touch top and bottom

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12594/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-and-dipaks)

Comment: Check the final - http://jsfiddle.net/H2d77/4/ you only had to play with the padding of it